# Tell if running process is running under Rosetta or is M1-native by Command Line

Tags: terminal, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

If you have an M1-based Macbook you can tell if a process running on the machine is Apple/M1 or Intel/Rosetta in Activity Monitor, but is there a way to get this information on the command line?

I'd like to be able to quickly show a count of how many Intel processes are currently running on my machine under Rosetta.

[image: Image of activity monitor showing Architecture]

Comment: Have you got a screenshot you can share of activity monitor output?

Comment: It's definitely possible to tell from within the process (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment) - i.e. you can make something that is aware of whether it's running in rosetta or not.

Comment: @MrR: yes: https://ibb.co/VTspjVj  See the "Architecture" column on the right side.

Answer (score 15):

TL,DR: `fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime`

I know how to see which processes are non-native. I don't know how to tell between different non-native architectures, but in practice there's only one

A non-native process has the Rosetta runtime open. You can use [`fuser`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fuser&apropos=0&sektion=1) to list which processes have a given file open. You can use [`lsof`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports+13.0) to see what files a given process has open.

```
$ arch -x86_64 sleep 868686 &
[1] 65444
$ sleep 123123123 &
[2] 65446
$ fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime
/usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime: 65444
$ lsof -p65444 -p65446 | grep /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime
sleep   65444 gilles  txt    REG   1,18    220064 1152921500312773394 /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime
```

You'll need `sudo` to see other users' processes (but normally system processes should be native).

Answer (score 4):

Here is some snippet to check all Rosetta 2 pids and inspect them:

```
ps -p `fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime | sed -e 's/.*: //' | sed -e 's/ /,/g'`
```

Comment: or ``ps -p `fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime 2> /dev/null` ``

Comment: `ps: option requires an argument -- p` is returned if no rosetta `pid` processes are running.

Answer (score 4):

This actually can be done with AppleScript if you know the PID of the process:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to return architecture of processes whose unix id is 758'
```

Comment: Even better: you can do `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to return name of processes whose architecture is "x86_64"'` to get Intel processes, and `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to return name of processes whose architecture is "arm64"'` for Apple Silicon ones.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of pids (one per line):

```
fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime 2>/dev/null | xargs -n1
```

You can then use it to filter with `grep`:

```
ps aux | grep -f <(fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime 2>/dev/null | xargs -n1)
```

Comment: How does this differ or improve from this existing answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431166/237

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely rule out some things (go to the terminal).
e.g.

```
# ps -ef | grep -i firefox$
  502 56288     1   0 11Mar21 ??       207:43.89 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

USE the executable name and pass to `file` command.

```
# file /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

So if that gives you x86_64 it has to be running under Rosetta - it's got only x86_64 architecture (the pre-M1 one).

On a M1 machine some things ship with universal binaries - for instance do the same thing for Safari and I get something like this (sorry machine is air-gapped .. this is TCP-over-ME so may not be 100% correct :-)

```
# file /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari:Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach_o 64 bit executable x86_64][arm64e:Mach-o 64-bit executable arm64e]
```

.. and then proceeds to give output that is for each architecture ... According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment#Determine-Whether-Your-App-Is-Running-as-a-Translated-Binary) it will "prefer" arm64e.

Comment: Off topic, but: "sorry machine is air-gapped .. this is TCP-over-ME" That's not an air gap!

Comment: This just shows for which architectures a binary is compiled, it doesn't show the architecture it's running under.