# Different apps stopped working after updating to Monterey 12.3.1 from 12.2.1

Tags: applications, software-update, crash, monterey, third-party

Yesterday I have updated my M1 Mac mini from 12.2.1 (or .2) to 12.3.1. I had some work apps opened (vscode, figma, slack, firefox..) so I decided to let the Mac update given that my work day was over.

So I start the update, leaving all of my apps opened (as I always do, I mean, I don't close the apps before an update, the OS will close them when it restarts).
The updater ask me to reboot and I click reboot now. At this point I leave my desk as I know it can take a bit. I return after some minutes and I see that the Mac has finished updating, cool.

I go and try to open Firefox, it starts, but it's stuck, it can't to anything. So I try with vscode, same, crashing. Then I open Slack, crashes. Figma, crashes.

I contacted the support, followed the procedure: created new admin user, no luck, safe mode, same errors, reinstall the OS, same errors. During the last contact I had with Apple they said that might be caused by the apps themselves rather than the OS and that I should contact their support but they will open a ticket.

Also tried to reinstall all of these apps and there is always the same problem. Tried also to download some more apps which are optimised for M1 which I did not had installed when I updated (downloaded Edge, Brave, vscode insiders, opera) and I always see the same behaviour.

The only way of making the apps work is to open them with rosetta.

Suggestions?

Here's a [gif](https://tinyimg.io/i/iZUoprU.gif) of the problem

Edit: this is the output I get from

```
ps -p $(sudo fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime 2> /dev/null)
```

```
      PID TTY           TIME CMD
  282 ??         0:00.72 Core Audio Driver (Background Music Device.driver)
  521 ??         0:04.00 /Library/Application Support/Logitech.localized/Logite
  553 ??         0:00.23 /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/XPCS
  567 ??         0:00.26 /Applications/AdBlock.app/Contents/PlugIns/AdBlock-Ext
 1001 ??         0:01.40 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
 1002 ??         0:00.01 /Users/*myusername*/Library/Application Suppo
 1008 ttys000    0:00.02 login -fp *myusername*
 1009 ttys000    0:00.04 -zsh
```

Comment: Well, if you already reinstalled the OS anyway, the fact that you had applications open before the upgrade most probably isn't relevant. Can you use one of the methods in 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416036/tell-if-running-process-is-running-under-rosetta-or-is-m1-native-by-command-line?rq=1 to check whether Finder is running via Rosetta?

Comment: Or any other "core" processes? Especially the output of `ps -p $(sudo fuser /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime 2> /dev/null)` should ideally be empty.

Comment: The Rosetta factor would seem to be the crucial factor. *Something* is definitely configured wrongly, and that's survived a re-install of the OS; but it's outside of the user domain. Hmm. See if there's anything useful in the system.log.  But I'd be tempted to do a wipe, clean install of the OS, and then carefully migrate stuff --hopefully without migrating the rogue configuration.

Comment: Incidentally, there's nothing worse than setting your Mac to install a system update, only to find that it hasn't happened because some app won't quit without user intervention. Always better to make sure that they're going to close!

Comment: Edited the post with the output of the command @nohillside

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll pay attention to that next time @benwiggy

Comment: Hmm, nothing unexpected here (assume you run iTerm via Rosetta because of the problem this is all about). When you reinstalled the OS, did you wipe the system first or just reinstall the OS? If you did the latter, maybe try as benwiggy said.

Comment: Maybe I set iTerm to run via Rosetta for some compatibility issue I had installing stuff a while ago. Is working fine also when running natively, I just checked

Comment: Would you recommend a clean install of 12.3.1 or should I install the previous version?

Comment: Is it safe to share the system.log here?

Comment: A clean install of 12.3.1 should be ok (in theory). I have a M1 Mini as well and did the same procedure as you did, but without any hiccups.

Comment: Hmm, if iTerm works ok when running natively, this makes it even more strange that Firefox, Slack, VSCode won't work. Can you try some more applications, maybe there is a pattern here?

Comment: As said in the original post, I've tried different apps. Also new apps that were never installed on my Mac before, like Brave Browser, Opera, VSCode Insiders, all of these produce same crash behaviour.

Other optimised apps works fine (iTerm, Surfshark, AndroidStudio, Alfred, Amphetamine, VLC)

Comment: Can you physically disconnect your Mac completely from all networks (turn off WiFi, unplug Ethernet, etc.) and see if this behavior persists?

Comment: Still experiencing the issue after disconnecting from network @pion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try approaching this from first principles. You have some but not all third-party apps that are hanging at startup, with no clear differentiator between working and broken apps. We should look inside the call stacks of both sets of apps and find what is holding up the main event loop in the latter case. The way to do this is by collecting and analyzing a **spindump**. To do this:

1. Run the following *Terminal* command to enable kernel symbolication:

   ```
    sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"
   ```

   Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a general error, you will first need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection). You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. **Reboot your machine** and don’t open any apps except for *Terminal*.
3. In *Terminal*, enter the following command, press <kbd>Return</kbd>, type in your password, but **do not press <kbd>Return</kbd> again yet**:

   ```
    sudo spindump -reveal -noProcessingWhileSampling
   ```
4. Launch a **known working app**, let it reach an idle state, and write down the name of the app.
5. Launch a **known broken app** and once you confirm that it is hanging, go to the *Terminal* window where you entered your password and press <kbd>Return</kbd> so that the command begins to execute. Do not do anything else on the computer while this command is running, otherwise you will distort the data collection. Write down the name of the broken app while you wait.
6. After waiting for >10 seconds to collect a sample and another minute or two to symbolicate and format, you’ll get a file in `/tmp/spindump.txt` that contains a stackshot of every process.
7. Upload the file to [PasteBin](https://www.pastebin.com) or some equivalent place and add the link to it to your original question. Make sure to tell us the names of the working and broken apps.

Comment: AFAIK there is no NVRAM on M1 machines.

Comment: @nohillside on Apple Silicon it’s implemented differently than on Intel but it’s exposed through the common NVRAM interface

Comment: This is a superb write up on how to use spin dump - well done!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this.

apparently this

`sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`

fixed everything. 
I was going through the steps and when I reached the step 5, I launched brave browser, it's opening fine, weird, I give Figma a try, opening without issues and basically all other apps that were not working are now working as expected.

Do you have an idea of how that command fixed this?

Comment: @zak182 It certainly isn't a direct fix; it either caused a helpful side effect or something else changed coincidentally around the same time. Too many possible causes and we don't have enough data to conclude anything. Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it works for you, and feel free to un-accept later on if the problem returns and you're able to complete the investigation.

Answer (score 1):

If this were my mac, here’s the steps I would take.

1. [Start Apple Silicon Mac in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)
2. Connect USB drive and do a Time Machine Backup
3. While Time Machine is running - look over any unix tools / command line tools that might be excluded. Check for Recovered Items on the desktop and [Relocated Items](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/a-relocated-items-folder-appears-mac-mchl8ae423a3/mac)
4. Restart normally - spot check the backup and exclusions / manual files needing backup or copying to the cloud.
5. Reinstall latest OS Installer downloaded from App Store
6. Test

Test would be delete the new admin account that didn’t work and make a second new admin account after the OS Install. If that still fails, I would do a reinstall from Recovery and then erase install.

The alternative would be to break down each and every app failure - figure which work, which do not, look for commonalities or work on them one by one until you discover the source of the delayed start / early crash / termination. This would require log analysis and some other troubleshooting tips and tricks - but a new admin account usually solves for those, so I’d get prepared for an erase / restore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, giving this a try.

Currently downloading the whole Monterey (~12GB). Following the installation procedure, will my data be wiped?

Comment: Hi @zak182 The installer does not intentionally wipe a system, but your system is also not behaving. You need the backup more because things are broken already, not that upgrades  don’t take pains to preserve all your settings, apps and documents.